# MATLAB code for solving fractional order partial differential equation through q-homotopy analysis transform method (q-HATM)

Tags: laplace-transform, homotopy-theory, matlab, fractional-calculus

Currently, I'm doing research about fractional order partial differential order and trying to solve it using homotopy analysis method with Laplace transform which is known as q-HATM. Then, solve the equations using MATLAB software but I have searched all the web and couldn't find anywhere. Perhaps someone can help me provide MATLAB code or link to refer? Because this is for my master's thesis.